# How to populate GridView from the Json Response

Tags: android, json, gridview

i want to Show User in grid view(with user image) My jsonArray is giving me correct Response (User_id,User_image,User_full of 3 Users)

my Question is that How to Show That three users in grid view And And Make Click able

is There Any Example To show these User in GRID VIEW ...i Know i have to Make Set Adaptor  but How ????????

```
[3]
0:  {
User_Id: "47"
User_Full_Name: "pragya Singh"
 User_Image: "http://www.get2love.webitexperts.com/profile_images/1400734158bg.jpg"
 }-
 1:  {
       User_Id: "57"
       User_Full_Name: "meet"
       User_Image: ""
     }-
 2:  {
    User_Id: "67"
    User_Full_Name: "meet"
    User_Image: ""
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is a sample grid adapter. You can pass the user object array to the grid adapter , design a layout for each user row, and in getView() method, inflate the layout and set the values for the views based on position from the array.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Drawable> images;
LayoutInflater inflater;


public GridAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Drawable> images,
        int backgroundType) {

    this.images = images;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if (convertView == null) {

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_item, null);

    }

    ImageView ivImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
    ivImage.setImageDrawable(images.get(position));
    return convertView;
}
```

}